# Android camera not working in KitKat

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera-intent

I'm trying to get Camera to work in KitKat. Hopefully, the community can help me understand why following logcat excerpt is happening:

```
E/CameraService(  155): CameraService::connect X (pid 5468) rejected (invalid cameraId 0).
W/CameraBase( 5468): An error occurred while connecting to camera: 0
```

My device is the Endeavoru, using CM ROM and vendor (CM-11.0) trees. My complete logcat up to the above error can be accessed on [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/Jcz6D11B).

This is an excerpt of my `last_kmsg.log`.

```
[    5.149688] rawchip_driver_probe
[    5.149905] setup_rawchip_cdev
[    5.150112] [CAM]rawchip_spi_init
[    5.150547] [CAM]:spi_rawchip_probe
[    5.151137] setup_rawchip_cdev rawchip: success
[    5.151803] tegra_camera tegra_camera: tegra_camera_probe
[    5.153107] s5k3h2y sensor driver loading
[    5.153397] s5k3h2y_probe: probing sensor.
[    5.154085] [CAM] s5k3h2yx_sysfs_init: kobject creat and add
[    5.154331] [CAM] s5k3h2yx_sysfs_init:sysfs_create_file
[    5.154735] [CAM] camera_led: kobject creat and add
[    5.155124] [CAM] ov8838 sensor driver loading
[    5.155468] [CAM] s5k6a1gx03 sensor driver loading. s5k6a1gx03_init
[    5.155942] [CAM] s5k6a1gx03_probe: probing sensor.
[    5.156468] [CAM] s5k6a1g power on ++
[    5.160928] [CAM] check_sensor_module: front camera uses s5k6a1
[    5.161143] [CAM] s5k6a1g power off ++
[    5.164112] [USB] send connect type -1
[    5.164328] [USB] wake_lock
[    5.164557] [BATT] cable USB at 5145529002 (1970-01-01 00:00:13.785525002 UTC)
[    5.186277] [CAM] s5k6a1g:kobject creat and add
[    5.186526] [CAM] s5k6a1g:sysfs_create_file
[    5.187074] [CAM] ad5823 sensor driver loading
[    5.187366] [CAM] ad5823: probing sensor.
```

It seems that the hardware is working, but you can access the full log on [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/9Gbg9wDm) if needed.